# What is the proper data structure for storing values with multiple keys?

Tags: database, nosql

I am new to nosql or document db. Please correct me if there is anything not clear. I am thinking about this question: What is the proper data structure for storing values with multiple keys?

An example can be probably a document with multiple tags, or a product with multiple alias. What could be an efficient way to store these pairs? If we use key-value store, is there a way to not duplicate value for each key?

For example, if we have a document with tags: "java", "algorithm", "data structure", are we going to keep one copy of the document for each tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the requests you need to make.

When using a KV store, you certainly will duplicate the tags: include them in the documents, to be able to display and document and the related tags; and create a list of document IDs for each tags, to allow you to get the list of documents for a given tag.

You have to ensure the consistency of data in your app: when you add a tag to a document, you add the document ID in the corresponding tag list.

Comment: Thank you! I think this makes sense now. Stupid me! I did not realize we could use documentID as the value.